# Migrating SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 to another environment

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-porter-2013-sp1

We have 3 instances of Tridion (Dev, QA, Prod) with some different configurations. Our content is out of sync now (Marketing team works only on prod, feature development happens in Dev) and we are moving to a workflow that keeps the environments better aligned.

We need to do a one-time migration of Prod content to Dev (and then Dev to QA). What is the easiest way to move this content? I want to make a backup of the content currently on Dev (for safety purposes) but ultimately I want to get rid of the outdated content that is currently there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard occurrence in all real life implementations. The Prod content is constantly evolving and we're left with outdated content on the lower environments. The solution is to do database rolldowns from time to time from your Production to the lower environments. This is a bit more complicated prior to Web 8 because there are some settings stored in the CM database which are related to the Content Delivery environment, for example, the Deployer address, Session Preview Web Service, Targeting, etc. Forget this, and you can end up in an unpleasant situations where you can publish to Prod from Dev (if infra did a sloppy job), so make sure to recreate the proper Publication Target(s) and their respective CD environment specific properties. In Web 8 these settings are located in a dedicated database so the rolldowns are easier and less error prone.

As you already mentioned, before the rolldown make sure to take a backup of your Dev DB just in case. Also, don't forget to backup all your in-progress development (templates, schemas, etc.). You can maybe do a Content Porter export of these items.

And finally keep in mind that this will also migrate the published states, so after importing the database to Dev, it's best to reset the publish states and publish everything. There might be some additional steps involved if you're using different domain users on the environments, but this is more of a specific issue, not present at every client.

Comment: Thanks! That was a very thorough answer. I guess where I've had the hardest time is finding any documentation on this. The official documentation is pretty difficult to sift through..

I don't mean to be dense, but I was "volunteered" into this role as the position was vacated. I am used to doing web dev, not CMS administration.

Comment: Am glad that it was useful, btw. if it answers your question, please consider marking the answer as accepted so the question becomes "closed".